# Characteristic classes for $E_8$ bundles

Tags: characteristic-classes, at.algebraic-topology, reference-request, vector-bundles

$\DeclareMathOperator\B{B}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$Given a principal $E_8$ bundle $P\rightarrow X$ one can take the
adjoint representation $\rho :E_8\rightarrow \SU(\mathbb C^{248})$
and form the associated vector bundle $V=P\times_{\rho}\mathbb
C^{248}$. This vector bundle has an $E_8$ characteristic class
$\lambda (V)\in H^4(X,\mathbb Z)$ obtained by pulling back the
generator $\lambda \in H^4({\B}E_8,\mathbb Z)$ and it has a second
Chern class $c_2(V)$ given by pulling back the generator $c_2\in
H^4({\B}{\SU}(248),\mathbb Z)$.

I am looking for a reference for the following fact:
$$\lambda (V)=\frac{c_2(V)}{60}.$$

There is the map ${\B}\rho^* : H^4({\B}{\SU}(248),\mathbb Z)\rightarrow
H^4({\B}E_8, \mathbb Z)$.  Since both groups are canonically
isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, the map is determined by a single
integer, which is the Dynkin index of $E_8$ and has been computed
to be $60$.  The above fact essentially follows from this.  I am
writing a paper and would prefer to just state the fact and then
point the reader to whoever first presented a thorough argument
filling in all the details. I have seen it mentioned as a footnote on page 68 in
[Vector Bundles And F Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9701162) by Friedman, Morgan, and Witten and some of the details regarding the Dynkin index are discussed in
[The torsion index of $E_8$ and other groups](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-05-12922-2) by Totaro.

Comment: I don't have an exact statement of this but I think it follows pretty simply from pages 452-454 of MF Atiyah, NJ Hitchin and IM Singer. {\sl Self-duality in four-dimensional Riemannian geometry}, Proc Roy Soc London Ser A, 362(1711), 425-461, 1978 and the fact that the first Pontrjagin class is \frac{1}{2} the second Chern class of the complexified tangent bundle.